# Create link_to for downloading a File from Paperclip gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

I'm building a file management system using the Paperclip gem and I need to download file.
What would be the parameters of the link_to method?

I have the following line in my model:

```
    has_attached_file :box
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose your model is Boxholder

If you have @boxholder instance variable in your controller like:

```
    @boxholder = Boxholder.find(params[:id])
```

Then the following line could be your solution:

```
    <%= link_to  @boxholder.box_file_name,@boxholder.box.url %>
```